# Iterate array for 2 model at once

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I have a listview design on a page and i want to print the value of those `models` in amount of 2 at a time. In short it should be like this

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <div>
        <img src="<?= $model->image ?>" />
        <a href="#"><?= $model->title ?> </a>
       </div> 
       <div>
        <img src="<?= $model->image ?>" />
        <a href="#"><?= $model->title ?> </a>
       </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But i cant figure out which loop should i use? As of now i am using foreach to get the `model` from `dataProvider` and display it one at a time and i am using below code right now

```
<ul>
   <?php foreach($dataProvider2->getData() as $record) { ?>
    <li>
       <img src="<?= $model->image ?>" />
       <a href="#"><?= $model->title ?> </a>
    </li>
   <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I want to display 2 item in one `<li>` and problem here is that the `dataProvider` may have results in odd or even number as well.

How can i manage that in the loop that if the array is in odd number than only prints one item in the last loop???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<?php
$data = $dataProvider->getData();
?>
<ul>
   <?php for($i = 0; $i <= count($data) - 1; $i++) : ?>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $data[$i]->id ?> </a>
        </div>

        <?php
        if ($i < (count($data) - 1) ) : ?>
        <div>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $data[$i + 1]->id; ?> </a>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </li>
    <?php $i++; ?>
   <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

Result:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#">1 </a>
        </div>

        <div>
           <a href="#">2 </a>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#">3 </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="#">4 </a>
        </div>
        </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#">5 </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="#">6 </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#">7 </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="#">8 </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#">9 </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#">10 </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: and does that include handling for odd number of data in array??? Anyway i am giving it a try now